# Vue 2 component prop getting wrong value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to build a  menu between categories. If a category has a sub-category it returns a value that says has_subCategory as boolean 0/1.

```
<template>
    <select><slot></slot></select>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

      props: ['value',
              'hasSubCat'],
      watch: {
        value: function(value, hasSubCat) {
          this.relaod(value);
          this.fetchSubCategories(value, hasSubCat);
        }
      },
      methods: {
        relaod: function(value) {

          var select = $(this.$el);

          select.val(value || this.value);
          select.material_select('destroy');
          select.material_select();

        },
        fetchSubCategories: function(value, hasSubCat) {
          var mdl = this;
          var catID = value || this.value;
          var has_subCat = hasSubCat || this.hasSubCat;

          console.log("has_subCat:" + has_subCat);

          mdl.$emit("reset-subcats");

          if (catID) {
            if (has_subCat == 0) {
              if ($('.subdropdown').is(":visible") == true) {
                $('.subdropdown').fadeOut();
              }
            } else {
              axios.get(URL.API + '/subcategories/' + catID)
                .then(function(response) {
                  response = response.data.subcatData;
                  response.unshift({
                    subcat_id: '0',
                    subcategory_name: 'All Subcategories'
                  });
                  mdl.$emit("update-subcats", response);

                  $('.subdropdown').fadeIn();
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                  if (error.response.data) {

                    swal({
                      title: "Something went wrong",
                      text: "Please try again",
                      type: "error",
                      html: false
                    });

                  }
                });
            }
          } else {
            if ($('.subdropdown').is(":visible") == true) {
              $('.subdropdown').fadeOut();
            }
          }
        }
      },
      mounted: function() {

        var vm = this;
        var select = $(this.$el);

        select
          .val(this.value)
          .on('change', function() {
            vm.$emit('input', this.value);
          });

        select.material_select();
      },
      updated: function() {

        this.relaod();
      },
      destroyed: function() {

        $(this.$el).material_select('destroy');
      }
    }
</script>


<material-selectcat v-model="catId" name="category" @reset-subcats="resetSubCats" @update-subcats="updateSubCats" id="selcat">
                    <option v-for="cat in cats" :value="cat.cat_id" :hasSubCat="cat.has_subCat" v-text="cat.category_name"></option>
                  </material-selectcat>
```

The data looks like this:

```
cat_id:"0"
category_name:"All Subcategories"
has_subCat:0
```

What I dont understand is that **console.log("has_subCat:" + hasSubCat);** prints out different values each time I change the select. It should only display **0** or **1**

Comment: Can you share an MCVE?

Comment: @Terry Updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watcher in vue.js is supposed to be used in order to watch one value, but you can fulfill your requirement with [help of `computed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

```
export default {
  props: ['value',
          'hasSubCat'],
  watch: {
    /* without this, watcher won't be evaluated */
    watcher: function() {}
  },
  computed: {
    watcher: function() {
      this.reload(this.value);
      this.fetchSubCategories(this.value, this.hasSubCat);
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

I also made a simplified working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/7en1312w/1/), you can have a look.

Comment: Ahhhh this line did it ``watcher: function() {}`` !

Comment: The only problem is that now the select will try to call my api once the page loads even though I have not selected a value. Also ``console.log("has_subCat:" + has_subCat);`` vill always return undefined. But I can se in my data that it does exist it just doesnt get passed to the ``fetchSubCategories();`` function

Comment: You can simply use a flag variable and turn it to true once selection happened.

Comment: @user2722667 I updated my fiddle, please have a look and see whether it makes sense. https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/n9f8rrqe/

Comment: console.log("has_subCat:" + has_subCat); still returns undefined

Comment: Is `console.log("has_subCat:" + has_subCat);` inside `this.fetchSubCategories`? Is `this.fetchSubCategories` invoked?

Comment: Yea, just like my code above  inside ``fetchSubCategories: function(value, hasSubCat)``

Comment: would you please check if the function's argument `hasSubCat` output as undefined or not?

Comment: It outputs undefined

Comment: So I'm wondering whether the prop `hasSubCat` is set correctly in `material-selectcat` tag.

Comment: If I check the VUE tab in my inspector I can see that the data does exist, and my html looks right so no idea : /

Comment: @user2722667 It sounds strange because if you look at the fiddle I provided, you can find out that props like `this.propA` and `this.propB` can be accessed without any problem.

Comment: You're right, it doesnt get passed at all. I have doubled check the spelling as well. No idea whats causing it

Comment: @user2722667 You mean you cannot access the prop `hasSubCat` in `mounted`?

Comment: No it doesnt return anything

Comment: @user2722667 OK, that means you'd better debug the parent component. The problem you encountered now has no business with the watcher thing.

Comment: Yea I accepted your answer. What I dont get is that ``<option v-for="cat in cats" :value="cat.cat_id" :hasSubCat="cat.has_subCat" v-text="cat.category_name"></option>`` outputs all values beside ``cat.has_subCat`` but if I check the vue tab in my inspector I can se that the has_subCat field/data exist for all objects/categories

Comment: My code states that material-selectcat is expecting a prop named subcat. Meaning the template expects <material-selectcat :subcat="(variable containing subcat)">. But I am passing the prop to an HTML tag which does nothing, not a vue component.

Comment: Great, glad you found the reason.

Comment: I love you man!

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the second parameter of your watch function is `hasSubCat` which is not the case. While the first parameter of the `value` watch function represents the new value of the property, the second parameter is actually the old value of the watched property. Try this out to understand more.

```
watch: {
   value: function(value, oldValue) {
     console.log('new value:', value)
     console.log('old value:', oldValue)
   }
}
```

So to watch both of `value` and `hasSubCat`, you can do something like this:

```
watch: {
  value: function(newValue) {
     this.reload(newValue)
     this.fetchSubCategories(newValue, this.hasSubCat)
  },
  hasSubCat: function(newHasSubCat) {
     this.reload(this.value)
     this.fetchSubCategories(this.value, newHasSubCat)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can watch both values?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I tried just that, but this will call the same API call twice since fetchSubCategories() is called in both watchers. I was wondering if I could "watch" both props using the same function

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call the API only once both props have changed?

Comment: Yes, "value" is the category id, "hasSubCat" is a boolean which says if the category has a subcategory, eg if hasSubCat = 1, then a api call should be made api.myApi/subcategory/{value}